# How can I change a window orientation to landscape in XCode 4 Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I appreciate I'm probably missing something basic here, but...

My iPad app will only support landscape mode, and has a MainWindow.xib Window that I'd like to work on in landscape mode in XCode 4, however the pull-down menu to change this (Simulated Metrics -> Orientation) is always grayed out.

I notice that Views can be rotated just fine, it's only Windows that can't be rotated in XCode 4 using this setting.

Is there a workaround for this, or do I have to put a View on top of the MainWindow in order to rotate it?

Comment: Have just had the same question...

Comment: Hi Johannes, nobody seems to know, so I'm going to assume I have to put a View on top of the main window just so I can rotate in the editor - annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because apps always starts up in portrait and then rotates to appropriate oriantations. From the `UIViewController` docs:

> Note: At launch time, applications should always set up their
>   interface in a portrait orientation. After the
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method returns, the
>   application uses the view controller rotation mechanism described
>   above to rotate the views to the appropriate orientation prior to
>   showing the window.

So you'll need the `UIViewController` magic for the simulated metrics to make any sense. If you used the "Window-based application" template as a starting point for your project try the "View-based application" template instead.

Comment: Thanks, I've more or less done this already, and gave up trying to do everything on a Window. I have a UIViewController on top that supports Landscape mode.