# how to change mainwindow.xib's orientation to landscape?

Tags: landscape

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change a window orientation to landscape in XCode 4 Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153271/how-can-i-change-a-window-orientation-to-landscape-in-xcode-4-interface-builder)

i create a window-based application,and the orientation of mainwindow.xib is Portrait,i want to change it to landscape,so how can i do?please see the following image

[image]

the orientation can not be changed,so how can i do?thanks